# How to select and upload multiple images from Media Storage

Tags: magento2

I want to select and upload multiple images from Media Storage. In default functionality I have to open Media Storage and go to the specific folder again and again to upload new image. How can I achieve that I can select and upload multiple images in Media Storage.

Comment: Do you want this In product?

Answer (score 0):

Check below screenshot

[image]

Press **CTRL** key until your selection will not complete.

By this way, you can select multiple images